# How to hook for MFC CWnd Creation

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, hook

I am very new to this website and new to hooking and C++.

I want hook to MFC application window creation:

Can this be done using C# code?

We have followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) site to listen to window creation. We have used `WH_CBT` instead of mouse related constana and did the required changes to hook for window creation. But it is not working. Is it the right way to do?

If the above approach is wrong to hook to MFC window creation, then please suggest an approach to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot install that type of hook from C#.

There are only two hooks that do not require DLL injection: the low-level keyboard and mouse hooks (`WH_LL_KEYBOARD` and `WH_LL_MOUSE`). Since managed DLLs cannot be injected into unmanaged processes, none of the other types of hooks can be used from C#.

You will need to write this hook DLL in native code instead; something like C or C++. Aside from that, a CBT hook ([`WH_CBT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#wh_cbthook)) is exactly what you want. Although this hook will alert you when *any* window is created, not just those using the MFC framework. You'll have to figure out some way of filtering out these false positives for yourself.

Comment: **You'll have to figure out some way of filtering out these false positives for yourself**.  How can i do?

Comment: @raj I'll need more information about what problem you're trying to solve in order to answer that question. Is this an application that you've created? Does it have a unique window caption? Perhaps a unique window class name? Why do you need to hook MFC window creation in the first place? Why can't you solve the problem a different way?

Comment: As per my seniors this one of the best way. I don't created it. **Window has unique class name**

Comment: Weird that they know so much about it, but can't help you actually do it. I suspect they're wrong, this is not really the best way to do much of anything. You still haven't told me what the goal is. @raj

Comment: Gray, As per our project requirement we are supposed to get access to a particular MFC object handle. This MFC object is inherited from CWnd class. So, now we could establish the hooking for the window creation but we need to filter it. So, we thought we can do the filtering using 'ClassName' property of the window. Can that be done? If so could you please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: @Raj Yes, that will work. You'll get an HWND value inside of the hook procedure. Call the [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx) function to fill a buffer with the name of that window's window class. Compare that to the class name string you're expecting. If they match, you've got your window.